# How do I setup a Submit Button to save text in the text field once submitted?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, textfield

So I know how to add a text field, and a submit button. However, the submit button does nothing but refresh the page and my text is lost.

I posted another question on here and found out that I have to setup the button with php and a database to save the text to. PHP is out of my league.
All I am looking for is a simple text field that you can write in, with a submit button. When the submit button is clicked all it does is keep the text that was written inside the text field stay in the text field until deleted and the submit button is clicked again to make the changes, as to what you just deleted in the text field.

Is it really that complicated to setup something that sounds so simple?
I don't know PHP nor JS, I know html and css but that's all for now. I plan on expanding my languages but time has been an issue lately for awhile lol.

Any help and guidance, maybe an example of it or something to just show me what I have to do to get the text to just stay in the text field once submitted.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

ok
here is your form :

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Enter text">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

now make a save.php file beside your html file and copy these file into your save.php file
note : you need to make a database and table inside it,then edit connection data with yours to make it work.

```
  <?php
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        $text = $_POST['text'];

        echo $text;

        //db connection
        try {
        /*** connect to SQLite database ***/
$servername = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$username = 'root';
password = '';
        $dbh =new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $dbh= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName (text) 
    VALUES (:text)");

            $dbh->bindParam(':text', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $dbh->execute();

        /*** fetch the results ***/
        $result = $dbh->fetchAll();

        /*** loop of the results ***/
        foreach($result as $row)
            {
            echo $row['text'].'<br />';

            }


        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }


    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I am confused about creating a table in the new database. What table do I need to add to it?

Comment: create a database name it whatever you want then create a table name it 'tableName' if you don't want edit my code @Jon

Comment: Ok that's done. When I create the table. How should I fill out the structure for it? I greatly appreciate all of your help!!! You're teaching me very useful skills and saving me money and time! So I thank you!!! @moeinrahimi

Comment: I recommend you to read this article about creating database and table : [link]https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_create_database.htm and also you may mark my answer as the correct answer for you question @Jon

Comment: Well the only thing is, the text is not staying in the text field box.
I want it so that it's a large text field, on my admin page in Magento. And when someone writes something in the large text field and finishes writing a task or a note for another employee, they then click the Submit Button. When clicked, the page will refresh and the text that was put in the large text field stays in the large text field after the page has finished refreshing. And the only way to get rid of it is simply by clicking on the text and deleting it (backspace) then hit submit again.

Comment: No one able to help me out with the whole "text stays in test field on button submit click"? :(